# What are the rules plone works with to decide which menus to display, and when?

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone 4.0.5, and I've spent the day trying to understand plone.app.contentmenu.

I have a custom folder based archetypes type, and I've written a view for it.  When using the default base_view (site/MyObject/base_view), everything works as expected.  Using my own custom view though, the menus start disappearing, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

First, my zcml,

```
<browser:page
  for="my.product.interfaces.IMyType"
  name="view"
  class="my.product.browser.mytype.MyTypeViewView"
  permission="zope.Public"
/>
```

The view itself is as simple as possible:

```
class MyTypeViewView(BrowserView):
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile("templates/mytype_view.pt")
    def __call__(self):
        return self.template()
```

And the view template has also been slimmed down to nothing:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="plone">
<body>
<metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
  hi there.
</metal:content-core>
</body>
</html>
```

If I access site/MyObject/view, the template shows "hi there", but plone-contentmenu-actions and plone-contentmenu-workflow disappear.  plone-contentmenu-factories however, remains.  if I then modify the ZCML to set name="view_test", and visit site/MyObject/view_test, none of the menus at all display.

I have five different views for this type, and I want the workflow menu to display on all of them (or at the very least, my main view, so that I can test more easily until I figure it out).

If I rename my view to base_view and visit the object URL directly, I still don't have a workflow menu available.

I guess my question should be:

What exactly are the rules plone works with to decide which menus to display, and when? What code should I be reading?

-- edit:

I've added this function to my View:

```
def __init__(self, context, request):
    super(MyTypeViewView, self).__init__(context, request)
    alsoProvides(self, IViewView)
    alsoProvides(self.context, IViewView)
```

if I place a breakpoint in my **call** code, I get this:

```
>>> IViewView.providedBy(self)
True
>>> IViewView.providedBy(self.context)
True
```

I'm pretty sure I only needed to apply IViewView to the view itself, but regardless, this doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: If you're view is not the canonical view, but you still want to show those viewlets then you should add `implements(IViewView)` at the class level. Never set IViewView on the context.

Comment: I **was** doing it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: No. Not fixed.  I will report here when I finally figure it out, but that's for another day.

Comment: I also discovered, and will note here for posterity, that the review_state variable *really* should be called review_state, and the TTW form at portal_workflow calls it 'state' by default, which causes similar symptoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a view Class (MyTypeViewView) for your page it's more straight-forward to make it implement the interface instead of make instances of it provide it:

```py
from plone.app.layout.globals.interfaces import IViewView

class MyTypeViewView(BrowserView):
    interface.implements(IViewView)

    ...
```

Although I think that this won't solve your problem since I do have lots of custom views that do not implement IViewView but display all actions nicely.

I guess you simply need to add your views to the available default views for your type in portal_types tool and you're fine.

Comment: I discovered that I was importing and rendering multiple view templates in my view, which all implemented IFolderContentsView.  Obviously, Plone can't know which one is actually the folder contents view, and which ones are used for their utility value.  However, adding IViewView is not effective, ad adding them to default views for my type as you mention, does directly affect this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Plone applied the IViewView marker interface to the view which are canonical for an object - the one you get clicking the view tab. Certain parts of the interface are restricted to that interface - see the section "Restricting a viewlet to the canonical view" in http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/five.grok/browser-components/viewlets

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing it wrong :/  I've made an edit above; this is good info (thank you), but doesn't appear to solve my problem.